# Need to find element with selenium, getting an error Unable to find element with class name

Tags: python, selenium

I need to scrap information from a page (Edit: removed NSFW link) page. Before entering the page, there's a button I should click to be able to get the page itself. Im using `Python 2.7.10` and selenium, with `PhantomJS 1.9.8`.

Heres my code:

```
#!/bin/env/python
# -*- coding: cp1250 -*-
import urllib
import urllib2
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys, os
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("cp1250")

base_url = "https://www.24dolores.pl/"
waiting_time = 20

def get_browser():
    return webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs.exe")

def download_page_src(url):
    try:
        browser = get_browser()
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
        browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        close = browser.find_element_by_class_name('.enter_pl')
        close.click()
        html = browser.page_source
        browser.close()
        return html
    except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
        return error
    except urllib2.URLError, error:
        return error
    except Exception, error:
        return error

page = download_page_src(base_url)
print page
```

And the error it gives:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\student>cd C:\Documents and Settings\student\Pulpit

C:\Documents and Settings\student\Pulpit>python test.py
Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with class name '.enter_pl'","r
equest":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Co
nnection":"close","Content-Length":"98","Content-Type":"application/json;charset
=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:1708","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":
"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"class name\", \"sessionId\": \"1d0a4
d60-add2-11e5-84a6-b5f372943a74\", \"value\": \".enter_pl\"}","url":"/element","
urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/ele
ment","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInf
o":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["
element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/1d0a4d60-add2-11e5-84a6-b5f372943a74/element"
}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Comment: Srsly? NSFW link? It's just the page I need the data from ... Why downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the dot of the class name. 
If you want to keep using css selector you do:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".enter_pl")
```

Comment: The error is the same, btw, theres no such method like `get_element_by_css_selector`, its `find_element_by_css_selector`

Comment: Find instead of get, my bad

Comment: My way of work in those cases is to try simulate the case on my browser. Open inspector and first run, $('.enter_pl') .

Comment: I know that. It works with Firefox: http://pastie.org/private/b9opevxrhjvpiihidikha but the problem is I need it to work with PhantomJS.